# Defining the capacity of a multi-dimensional arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have created a class called `Grid` and I'm struggeling to define the capacity of a nested `ArrayList`. This is what I currently have:

```
public class Grid extends GameObject {

   private int cols;
   private int rows;
   private int colWidth;
   private int rowHeight;
   private ArrayList<ArrayList<GameObject>> contents;

   public Grid(int x, int y, int cols, int rows, int colWidth, int rowHeight, ID id) {
       super();
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.cols = cols;
       this.rows = rows;
       this.colWidth = colWidth;
       this.rowHeight = rowHeight;

       //Here I want to define the contents

       this.width = colWidth * cols;
       this.height = rowHeight * rows;
       this.id = id;
   }
 }
```

The code should look something like this:

```
this.contents = new ArrayList<ArrayList<GameObject>(cols)>(rows);
```

But this gives an error. Does anyone know how to solve this issue, I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with a single initialization statement. You need a loop.

```
this.contents = new ArrayList<ArrayList<GameObject>>(rows); // this creates an empty 
                                                            // ArrayList
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { // this populates the ArrayList with rows empty ArrayLists
    this.contents.add(new ArrayList<GameObject>(cols));
    // and possibly add another loop to populate the inner array lists
}
```

Comment: I kinda hoped it was possible, but this will have to do. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Define the size when you create the list.

```
contents = new ArrayList<>(x);

contents.add(new ArraysList<GameObject>(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot do that as from the application point of view, it is single dimention list. Also `new ArrayList<?>(N)` does not define the maximum capacity of list (like `new GameObject[N]` would), but it defines its **initial capacity**. After adding N elements to that list, you will still be able to add more as internally another array will be allocated, bigger then N this time, and the content will be copied.

You need to look trough every dimension and create new list with optional initial capacity set.